# How do eigenpairs of a matrix change if I take log of all the elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, logarithms

Assuming that A $\in R^{+n}$ and is symmetric, how will eigenvalues and eigenvectors change if I take the natural log of all its elements? Is there anything we can say about how they change?
I did a thorough search, but couldn't find anything except for logarithm of a matrix (but not its elements) which is useless in my case.

Comment: It's very doubtful that something can be said... as the operation is highly non-linear.

Comment: Additionally, eigenvalues are not stable under perturbation. So even small changes in the matrix values may lead to huge changes in the eigenvalues.

Comment: As to how they will change: ***totally.*** And unpredictably, too.